# how do I increase the cardView Size based on the text size?

Tags: android, android-studio, text-size, android-components

If I change the text size it will overflow my cardview **how do I change the cardview size to adjust to the current textview size?**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
card_view:cardElevation="1.5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
android:onClick="OnClick">
```

Comment: Can you please post the layout xml? Does your cardview has a fixed size?

Comment: why you don't use wrap_content?
if you want to have different size, when you change size of font size, then change size of card view programmatically.

Comment: if you want to increase cardview height with textview's text size, use `wrap_content` for height.

Comment: Like the others say, use wrap_content.

Comment: You could set the height as the others said to wrap content and add additionally min height 120dp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change size of cardview than according to text size than change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1.5dp">
```

**EX :** I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#85c7dc"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1.5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDrVisit_DrName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDrVisit_DrDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="ABC"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```